# Events available for PrimeFaces p:selectOneListbox

Tags: java, events, jsf, primefaces

Where can I find the events available for PrimeFaces 3.2? I am having a problem with the unselect. After the unselect event, the value is not set to null. It remains the old value.

I have tried without success with the `<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{bean.onRowUnselect}" />` and inside the bean the unselect handler is declared like this: `public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {`.

Comment: User guide is the best source: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html. Provide your selectOneListbox part from xhtml and POJO

Comment: I haven't found any information there.